# ubuntu gcc error cannot find -lut

Tags: gcc, linux-headers

When compile with gcc getting error:

> ERROR /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lut

What is the missing library name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker expands `l` to `lib`, so the missing library name will be `libut` (either as a shared library like `libut.so` or a static library `libut.a`)

Using `apt-file` we can search for the containing package:

```
$ apt-file search /libut\.
uthash-dev: /usr/include/libut.h
uthash-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libut.a
```

From `apt-cache show uthash-dev`:

```
Description-en: hash table and linked list for C structures
 uthash-dev provides a hash table implementation using C preprocessor macros.
 This package also includes:
  * utlist.h provides linked list macros for C structures
  * utarray.h implements dynamic arrays using macros
  * utstring.h implements a basic dynamic string
```

Alternatively, it's possible that `libut` is a private library provided by the software that you are trying to build.